# What's Amazon Web Services *native* offering is closest to Apache Kudu?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, bigdata, bigtable, apache-kudu

I am looking for a **native offering**, such as any of the RDS solutions, Elastic Cache, Amazon Redshift, not something that I would have to host myself.

From the Apache Kudu: https://kudu.apache.org/ :

```
 Kudu provides a combination of fast inserts/updates and efficient columnar 
 scans to enable multiple real-time analytic workloads across a single storage 
 layer. As a new complement to HDFS and Apache HBase, Kudu gives architects the 
 flexibility to address a wider variety of use cases without exotic workarounds.
```

As I understand it, Kudu is a columnar distributed storage engine for tabular data that allows for fast scans and ad-hoc analytical queries but ALSO allows for random updates and inserts. Every table has a primary key that you can use to find and update single records...

Answer (score 3):

Second answer after question was revised.

The answer is Amazon EMR running Apache Kudu.

Amazon EMR is Amazon's service for Hadoop. Apache Kudu is a package that you install on Hadoop along with many others to process "Big Data".

If you are looking for a managed service for only Apache Kudu, then there is nothing. Apache Kudu is an open source tool that sits on top of Hadoop and is a companion to Apache Impala. On AWS both require Amazon EMR running Hadoop version 2.x or greater.

Comment: I am assuming that KUDU cannot use S3, or could it?

Comment: On EMR all services / applications that do not require modifying existing files can use S3. Anything designed for HDFS can use EMRFS.

Comment: so not kudu is my take here

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @thebluephantom - create a new question instead of using comments.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I upvoted. Answer is as expected, was just wanting to confirm.

Comment: @JohnHanley Kudu isn't designed to use HDFS. Since Kudu supports incremental updates, I suppose it can't be run on top of S3